# Diastereoselectivity of the Pauson Khand Reaction

Tags: organic-chemistry, stereochemistry

I hope someone may help me. I don‘t know how to determine the diastereoselectivity of the product of the Pauson Khand reaction in generally. 
In the following I’ve got 3 practice examples,however in the third one I’ ve got no solution. I know the product and the regioselectivity. 
[image]

Comment: Do you know the putative mechanism for the Pauson-Khand? That should help you. Or if you are familiar with Heck-type chemistry, you might be able to guess.

Comment: You should render an educated rationale for the stereochemistry in #3.

Comment: Here's a useful link http://stoltz2.caltech.edu/seminars/2009_Bennett.pdf